# instead of cron can i use infinite loop in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile, boot2docker

Here is a situation in my docker container, there are few files which we can push into the database and in container as per scheduled interval we check if there is any new file in the db, if yes then we pull that and use it inside the container.

So, to do the pulling job we are using corn job, there is this one .jar for execution of which we have done yun install of corn. My question what is wrong if I use infinite loop to execute the same .jar like

```
while true
do
    echo "loren"
    # execution desired command in this block.
    sleep $scheduled_Interval

done
```

As we are removing dependency on root user we are facing issue with corn when tried to run with non-root user. 
Your suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I know it's been a while but i'm faced with this question now.  Did you end up using the inifinite loop as cron substitute?

Comment: No, used corn only with proper access.